Establish a Connection between Databricks and Azure Service Bus Queue to send messages
I need to connect to Azure Service bus from Databricks (pyspark) in order to send json messages to existing queue
using a service principle or via AAD as auth.
I have tried the below code :
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage


#AAD and service Bus Details

tenant_id="my-tenanted"
client_id = "my-ClientID"
client_secret= "my client secret"

namespace="Azure Service Bus Hostname"
queue_name ="myqueue"


#Create Credential

credential=ClientSecretCredential(
        tenant_id=tenant_id
        client_id = client_id
        client_secret= client_secret
)


# Create a Service Bus client

servicebus_client= ServiceBusClient
(   fully_qualified_namespace=f"{namespace}.servicebus.windows.net"
    credential=credential
)


#Send a sample message

with servicebus_client:
         sender = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=queue_name)
         with sender:
             message=ServiceBusMessage("Hello,from Databricks")
             sender.send_messages(message)
             print("Message Sent")

Am getting an error like : "ServiceBusAuthenticationError" : Service Bus has encountered an error. Error Condition: amqp:client_error


Establish a Connection between Databricks and Azure Service Bus Queue to send messages:

You need to pass the connection string of an Azure service bus to establish a connection between resources. And also make sure that you have given Azure service bus data owner role to the client ID for sending or receiving messages.


Refer MSDoc for more relevant information on Azure service bus client library.
Use below modified code to achieve the above requirement.
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage

conn_str = 'Endpoint=sb://newbusi.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxU='


tenant_id = "xxxx"
client_id = "xxx"
client_secret= "xxxx"
namespace="newbusi"
queue_name ="queues"


credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)

servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(
            conn_str=conn_str,
            logging_enable=True
        )

with servicebus_client:
    with servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name) as sender:
        # Sending a single message
        single_message = ServiceBusMessage("Hello, from Databricks")
        sender.send_messages(single_message)
        print("Message Sent")

Output:


